# font not working properly in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm using this css but it is not working properly.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: OpenSans-Bold;
 src: url('../design_images/font/OpenSans-Bold.eot'); /* EOT file for IE */
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;

}
@font-face {
 font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
 src:url('font/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;

}

@font-face {
 font-family: Oswald-Regular;
 src: url('font/Oswald-Regular.eot');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;

}
@font-face {
 font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
 src: url('font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'); /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family:OpenSans-Bold;
 src: url('font/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: Oswald-Regular;
 src: url('font/Oswald-Regular.otf');
}

.newr {
        font-family:Oswald-Regular;
        font-size:20px;
        font-style:normal;
        font-smooth:Crisp;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#f9e211;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        margin:21px 0 0 25px;
    }
```

Comment: Define “not working properly” and specify the browser(s) used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two different paths in your src attribute. One is

> src: url('../design_images/font/OpenSans-Bold.eot'); /* EOT file for IE */

and the others are

> src:url('font/OpenSans-Regular.eot');

Why does one path link to `../design_images/font/` and the other just to `font/`? This may be your problem, depends on your directory structure. Just thought I'd point that out.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, I convert the regular fonts to webfonts to make them look smoother and cleaner, and add them in my CSS as something like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'ArvoRegular'; 
   src: url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.eot'); 
   src: url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.svg#ArvoRegular') format('svg'); 
   font-weight: normal; 
   font-style: normal; 
}
```

Search for @font-face Generators to generate your desired font.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
@font-face{
   font-family: fontFamilyNameHere ;
   src: url(.eot file path here); /* For IE */
   src: local("fontNameHere"), url(.ttf file path here) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */ 
   font-weight:normal;
   font-style:normal;
}
```